# How can I rotate() for a specific point?

Tags: svg

In MDN I can't find how to rotate a circle for a specific point for example (40,59), but I have seen someone write code like`transform="rotate(0, 400 100)"`.Can you tell me where did it define?

Comment: Well the code you shown is the way to go yes, use the second and third param of the [rotate func](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Rotate). i.e if you want the origin to be `40, 59`, that would be `rotate(∂, 40, 59)` where *∂*  is the angle value in degree.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot .